# In pandas, how to check if two strings match multiple columns in any of the rows in existing data frame and delete it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
                 rootID   parentID    jobID  time                         counter
              0    A         B          D    2019-01-30 14:33:21.339469      0
              1    E         F          G    2019-01-30 14:33:21.812381      0
              2    A         C          D    2019-01-30 15:33:21.812381      0
              3    E         B          F    2019-01-30 15:33:21.812381      0
              4    E         F          G    2019-01-30 16:33:21.812381      0
```

I will be fed live data, and the data is a rootID string, parentID string, jobID string and a date.

I want to check if the newly retrieved rootID and parentID combination already exists in the dataframe. So if I retrieve rootID = "A" and parentID == "B", jobID =="T" I want to access the first row of the dataframe. I then want to delete that row and append the new information and increment the update counter.

```
         IF rootID and parentID exist in the same row in dataframe. 
         delete row and append new data with updated jobID and incremented counter.
```

The dataframe should now look like

```
                 rootID   parentID    jobID  time                         counter
              0    E         F          G    2019-01-30 14:33:21.812381      0
              1    A         C          D    2019-01-30 15:33:21.812381      0
              2    E         B          F    2019-01-30 15:33:21.812381      0
              3    E         F          G    2019-01-30 16:33:21.812381      0
              4    A         B          T    2019-01-30 17:33:21.339469      1
```

Anyone have any idea how this could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would

```
root_id, parent_id, job_id = get_ids() # e.g. ('A', 'B', 'T')

cond = df.rootID.eq(root_id) & df.parentID.eq(parent_id) & df.jobID.eq(job_id)

df.loc[cond, ['time', 'counter']] = datetime.datetime.now(), df.loc[cond, 'counter']+1
```

This would update your data frame `in_place`. I wouldn't reorder the Dataframe all the time, unless it is absolutely needed. If you can, for example, re-sort it once a day, you can just

```
df.sort_values(by='time') #.reset_index(drop=True), if needed
```

periodically. However, if you absolutely have to change the rows at each time new data comes, then, assuming you have unique ids,

```
df = pd.concat([df[df[cond].index.item()+1:], df[cond]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get a pretty close solution just by translating your example :

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['rootID'] == rootID and row['parentID'] == parentID:
        df.drop(df.iloc[index])
        row['time'] = datetime.datetime.now()
        row['counter'] += 1
        df = df.concat(row)
```

Without loops:

```
selected_row = df[(df['rootId'] == rootID) & (df['parentID'] == parentID)])
df.drop(selected_row)
selected_row['time'] = datetime.datetime.now()
selected_row['counter'] += 1
df = df.concat(selected_row)
```

This assume you have only one row matching the rootID and parentID combination you are searching for.

Comment: avoid loops at all costs.

Comment: @RafaelC You're right. I edited for a solution without loops.